# Is it possible for 220V to have three phases?

Tags: three-phase

So, is it possible/does it exist that 220V has three phases?

Comment: Google 3 phase AC.

Comment: Yes. __________

Comment: If you want anything other than a one word answer, you might want to elaborate. 90% of your question is pointless filler text.

Comment: Norway uses 230 V line-line with no neutral in three-phase configuration. There might be other countries with the same arrangement too.

Comment: Depends on what voltage you measure: The common (in Europe) 400V 3-phase configuration has 400V phase-to-phase voltage and 230V phase-to-neutral voltage each.

Answer (score 8):

Any voltage can be supplied as three-phase. Various voltages are more popular in various parts of the world and in various usage situations. In the USA, 220-240 volt, three-phase has been used to some extent for small industrial installations, but 480 volts is much more popular for three-phase installations.